# Play Game Boy Color games on DS Lite

Tags: emulation, cheats, game-boy, nintendo-ds

I'm thinking about homebrew-hacking my DS Lite, because I could backup my games, play music, and emulate SNES games. I was thinking, could I emulate GBC games? I have a few timeless Gameboy Color games I like to play, and I hate having to carry around and old GBA just to play them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up [Lameboy](http://www.racketboy.com/retro/nintendo/gameboy/2008/07/best-gameboy-gbc-emulator-for-nintendo-ds-lameboy.html).